# Batch renaming files with decimal point extensions in linux

Tags: file, shell, decimal, rename

I have a batch of files with name like

- 000.100.dat
- 000.600.dat
- 001.100.dat
- 001.500.dat
- 007.600.dat

etc. I need them to be renamed by moving the decimal point up, say

- file000100.dat
- file000600.dat
- file001100.dat
- file001500.dat
- file007600.dat

A shell script to do this (to move around decimal place like this) would be great. If this is difficult in shell, a python script is also welcome. 
Thank You

Comment: Umm.. batch in linux? Don't you mean bash. *`I have a batch of files`*... Really

Comment: No.... the batch means the batch (group of files) contained by 001....dat, 003......dat etc.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you,

```
for f in *.dat; do
    a="file$(echo $f | sed '0,/RE/s/\.//')"
    mv "$f" "$a"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too:

```
for f in *.dat; do 
  ff=$(basename $f .dat) 
  echo mv "$f" "file$(echo -n "$ff"|tr -d '.').dat"
done
```